# Physics in blender 2.8 - can't interact with objects while simulation is running

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

Do this in both blender 2.8 and 2.79:

Create cube, enable rigid body physics, set to active, run animation, drag and release cube.

In blender 2.79 cube will act like a real life object, that is, it'll be "tossed" by a cursor drag. Doesn't work in 2.8, cube just jumps back in place.

Example - I can't do that in 2.8.

Comment: Show us your .blend file.

Comment: Try dragging the cube while simulation is running, it'll jump back in place after you release it. In blender 2.79 cube will act as if you tossed it.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Cf06yARXoM7g_zwpKvjlu0Ocmzovp_De

Comment: Bump please! I'm having this same problem in the official 2.8 release. When you grab (G) an object in an attempt interact with the simulation it freezes the objects that are currently in motion, but the playback (animation) continues to run.

Comment: I'm following [this Blender 2.79 tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ROE15KY97XM) on YouTube and the part at 18:03 - 18:14 doesn't seem to work in Blender 2.8. Could somebody else perhaps try this and confirm? Much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you looked deeper into this by now but as I'm also trying to achieve the same thing as Ben Clark might as well post my findings here.

I've done some messing and discovered that providing the object is set to be a passive rigid body you can grab it, move it where you want it and then reset the sim (timeline) and it will react correctly.

https://gyazo.com/987177ca2f87fef851519d8e12be3511

To me this looks like something to do with the physics caching system, maybe someone knows how to turn that off? :)

For a quick and dirty workaround, fascinatingly real-time grab physics still works with rigid body constraints.
Wouldn't be helpful if you want to just wack a cube wall with another cube though...

https://gyazo.com/75cdc85da98a0e7a3f67175c4386c9ee

Cheers!

Comment: Hi. Please upload any images using the built-in image uploader as a) this prevents the answer being less clear should external links break and b) this shows the images inline. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked when I activated animated in the rigidbody settings. (Sorry for the late answer)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it takes time for the computer to calculate the rest of the animation, especially if you have a large rigid body animation. It might crash blender if the load is to big. And I think think blender 2.8 implemented this so your computer doesn't take too much load. This is just what I think so I cant guarantee you that's it true.